# Is there a Silverlight Visualizer for viewing the children of an ItemsControl?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xaml

I am trying to debug the visual tree of a Silverlight app I am writing and I am having trouble with a specific ItemsControl.

Is there some sort of Debugger/Visualizer that I can use to inspect each child of the ItemsControl?

I am using Visual Studio in the code-behind of my xaml page right now, but I cannot inspect how each item of my ItemsControl is rendered at runtime. Is there a property (like Children) that I can inspect in my watch window? I have Silverlight 5 and Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/)?

Comment: That might be an option. Do you know of any free tools?

Comment: [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/) has free edition too (limited capabilities, but that's always something).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample project that uses LocalMessageReceiver/Sender

It dumps the Visual Tree into a separate application.

http://blog.aschommer.de/post/SilverDebugView.aspx